# R lidR catalog_laxindex() spatial index options

Tags: r, lidr

Is it possible to set the las catalog processing options to create .lax files by default?
Something like `lidR::catalog_laxindex(ctg) <- TRUE`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question! I wanted to anwser no but actually yes it is. You can tweak the driver used to write las files and set the argument `index = TRUE`

```r
ctg@output_options$drivers$LAS$param = list(index = TRUE)
```

But I do agree that a convenient access to the option would be useful.

Comment: Thanks, this is so much more convenient than writing the files, then reading in the output just to index the new files!

Comment: There is however a rational behind that. Originally I wanted people to use `lasindex` from `lastools` to perform the indexation rather that the function from `rlas`.